# All vs One non-parametric test?

Tags: nonparametric

I am currently analyzing several repeated measures with several treatments. That is: 33 individuals and 4 different conditions. The box plots that are shown from left to right indicate the treatments in the following order: control, first treatment, second treatment, and third treatment.

- Before adding more treatments to the analysis, I was obtaining statistical significant differences using a non-parametric Wilcoxon test between the control and the second treatment. Now, I am using a Friedman test for verifying differences in all treatments. The current obtained p value is 0.48, and I can't reject H0.

Is there a non-parametric test for comparing several treatments versus a control (control vs treatment1, control vs treament2, and control vs treament3) disregarding other comparisons? I think the reason Friedman can't visualize my previous difference between control and the second treatment is because of low statistical power.

Regards,
Ignacio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The box plots seem to tell an interesting story: Assuming they are in order, there are some complex things going on. I don't think any single test is going to tell the whole story. Wilcoxon was significant between the first two, but that seems solely due to higher highs - the medians are almost identical.

Therefore, I suggest quantile regression on a range of quantiles, with "group" as a categorical predictor.

Comment: I am sorry. The treatment I was talking in the description is the third one (third box plot), and not the second one. There are median differences between control and 3. However, between control and 2 wilcoxon does not reject H0.

Comment: Oh. You should perhaps edit your question saying which box is which.

Comment: Done! The theory I have found until now tells me that I can obtain p-values using Quantile regression. I will give it a try. Thanks for the answer!